# How do I make a pane fill up a side?

Tags: tmux

Say I have 3 panes two split vertically on top and 1 split horizontally below.

```
+------+----+
|  1   | 2  |
|      |    |
+------+----+
|  3        |
+-----------+
```

I would like pane 1 to fill up the space of pane 2. Basically, zooming pane 1 without affecting pane 3. If possible, I'd like to be able to toggle the zoom as well, similar to how `prefix` + <kbd>z</kbd> works.

Is this doable? I've been googling how to do this but haven't found any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box, you would have to write a script to move pane 2 somewhere else temporarily and move it back when you are done.